# parseDidEndDocument not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have the following code and for some reason the last three methods, `didEndElement`, `parserDidEndDocument` and `parseErrorOccurred` are not being called. The `NSLog`'s are not outputting text when the program runs. Oddly enough, the first three methods are being called. This leads me to believe it's not a delegate problem (as I have properly delegated everything) What's even more weird is that the last three methods only work when the `_query == "bookmarks"`. Anyway, here is my code:

```
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    NSLog(@"didstartdocument called");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"parsing...");
    NSLog(@"%@ found a %@ element", self, elementName);

    //IN TABLE VIEW
    if ([elementName isEqual:@"annotationsList"]) {
        // When we find an project item, create an instance of projectItem
        annotationObject = [[AnnotationObject alloc] init];

        // Set up its parent as ourselves so we can regain control of the parser
        [annotationObject setParentParserDelegate:self];

        // Turn the parser to the RSSItem
        [parser setDelegate:annotationObject];
        NSLog(@"REACHED ANNOTATIONS");


    }else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"bookmarkList"]){
        bookmarkObject = [[BookmarkObject alloc]init];
        [bookmarkObject setParentParserDelegate:self];
        [parser setDelegate:bookmarkObject];
        NSLog(@"REACHED BOOKMARKS");

    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"snippetsList"]){
        snippetObject = [[SnippetObject alloc]init];
        [snippetObject setParentParserDelegate:self];
        [parser setDelegate:snippetObject];
        NSLog(@"REACHED SNIPPETS");
        NSLog(@"count =  %lu",[[snippetObject snipItems] count]);


    }else{
        NSLog(@"REACHED ELSE");
    }


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    NSLog(@"did end element");
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
    NSLog(@"parseErrorOccurred called");
    if(parseError){
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",[parseError description]);}
    else{
        NSLog(@"NO PARSE ERROR");
    }
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    NSLog(@"starting filter...");
    if([_type isEqualToString:@"annotations"]){
        NSLog(@"filtering annotations...");
        for(int i = 0; i < [[annotationObject annotationItems]count];i++){
            if([[[[annotationObject annotationItems]objectAtIndex:i] annotationTitle] containsString:_query]){
                [_filtered addObject:[[annotationObject annotationItems]objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }

    }else if([_type isEqualToString:@"bookmarks"]){
        NSLog(@"filtering bookmarks...");
        for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [[bookmarkObject bookmarkItems] count];i++){
            NSLog(@"checking...");
            if([[[[bookmarkObject bookmarkItems]objectAtIndex:i] bmTitle] containsString:_query]){
                NSLog(@"match");
                [_filtered addObject:[[bookmarkObject bookmarkItems]objectAtIndex:i]];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"no match, title was %@ and query was %@",[[[bookmarkObject bookmarkItems]objectAtIndex:i ] bmTitle],_query);
            }
        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"filtering snippets...");
        for(int i = 0; i < [[snippetObject snipItems]count];i++){
            if([[[[snippetObject snipItems]objectAtIndex:i] snipTitle] containsString:_query]){
                NSLog(@"match");
                [_filtered addObject:[[snippetObject snipItems]objectAtIndex:i]];
            }else{
                 NSLog(@"no match, title was %@ and query was %@",[[[snippetObject snipItems]objectAtIndex:i ] snipTitle],_query);
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"DONE FILTER, filtered array length = %lu",(unsigned long)[_filtered count]);
    [_tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Close vote for "shortest code necessary" part.

Comment: @Almo:I'm sorry? My code is long but that's only because I'm debugging and did it in a rush...will clean it up later ;)